# Redirect wordpress page with variable

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Just created a website based on Wordpress and now I have the following problem. The old site which wasn't build in Wordpress used the variable `p=` for its pages just like Wordpress. Now I'm trying to redirect them but that doesn't work, I think because Wordpress also uses the p variable.

I want to redirect the page `http://purplethinking.nl/mauritshof/?p=brunch` to the page `http://purplethinking.nl/mauritshof/feestelijk/brunch`

I changed my `.htaccess` and added the following line:

```
RewriteRule ^/mauritshof/?p=brunch$ /feestelijk/brunch/[L]
```

Could you tell what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: Here is my complete .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mauritshof/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^mauritshof/?$ /feestelijk/brunch/ [L,R]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mauritshof/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule cannot work because:

- `RewriteRule` doesn't match QUERY_STRING.
- `RewriteRule` doesn't match leading slash
- You need a R flag for redirect

**Full .htaccess**:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mauritshof/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(brunch)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?$ /feestelijk/%1/? [L,R]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mauritshof/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I added these rules to my .htaccess, still no luck.

Comment: Can you paste your full .htaccess in your question.

Comment: I haved added my .htaccess file